# Flux failed to clone repository

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks, flux, fluxcd

Im trying to update my flux via bootstrap by following this documentation:
https://fluxcd.io/flux/use-cases/azure/#flux-installation-for-azure-devops
Im running this code, enter my password, and run in the error:

```
flux bootstrap git \
  --url=https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/mycomp/_git/myrepo \
  --branch=main \
  --password=${AZ_PAT_TOKEN} \
  --token-auth=true \
  --path=clusters/dev \
  --version=v0.35.0
```

Error

```
► cloning branch "main" from Git repository "https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/mycomp/_git/myrepo"
✗ failed to clone repository: unexpected client error: unexpected requesting "https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/mycomp/_git/myrepo/git-upload-pack" status code: 400
```

The repository link is working, the branch and path are available.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my Flux CLI wasn't at the same version as the cluster.